# JQuery Interview Question(From Beginners till Advance)

Tags: jquery

This may be a stupid question but however I searched in google with

"jquery interview questions" which didnot worked out much except for

[JQuery Interview Questions](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interview/ShowCatQuestion.aspx?category=97) and few sites with almost the sismilar question pattern(which are ultimately very basic).

Is there any good site where I can get JQuery questions starting from basic to advance.

Thanks

Comment: Try this [jQuery test](http://www.codelect.net/TestDetails/jQuery-Junior-Level-Test)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you hire someone based on a library, there is a serious problem there.

To be an "expert at jQuery", good knowledge of JavaScript is needed, since that's the language. Someone good at JavaScript should be able to pick up *any* library within a few days. Besides, jQuery isn't exactly brain surgery and most IDEs have support for it built in.

Comment: Agreed; jQuery should be very easy to pick up for anyone who is a JavaScript expert or knows another framework very well.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a question of hiring someone based on a library, but based on what they say they know. They claim to know jQuery, you want to assess that statement. In addition jQuery integrates JavaScript with CSS selectors and ideas about method chaining and iteration that have nothing to do with being a good JavaScript developer, except insomuch as a good JavaScript developer should know jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of ideas off the top of my head

Basic

- Provide an example of how to bind a click event to all paragraphs, except the last one (covers basic dom selection & event handling)
- Example of how to fade in a div from an invisible state

Advanced

- Write an selector filter to return only nodes with lower case values.

ie

```
$.expr[':'].lowercaseOnly = function(el, i, m) {
  ...
}
```

I also agree with @Coronatus answer. A good jQuery developer should have a solid knowledge of js.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to pick up jQuery if a developer has good understanding of JavaScript. You could ask questions where there is a strong overlap. Some not so common questions I can think of:

1. Implementing a function like `ready` for an external resource that is loaded only once. It must behave exactly like jQuery's ready function. If the resource is not yet loaded, it adds the callback function to be called later. Otherwise, it calls the callback immediately. Fire all stored callbacks when the resource loads.
2. What are [special events](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/) in jQuery, and where can they be used? Maybe make up an example of a composite touch event such as tap, and drag at the same time using two fingers.

Answer (score 0):

I recently put together an extensive list of jQuery Interview Questions. I still agree with most of the top answers here that jQuery is really not what you should base your skills on. That being said, here is a link to some of my favorite interview questions you should expect when trying to find a job in the industry where jQuery is being used.

[Commonly asked jQuery questions](http://simpledeveloper.com/jquery-interview-questions/)

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

They probably want a good understanding of the api concepts (http://api.jquery.com/). Some grasp of how ajax and javascript work is also useful as mentionned above.